# $(e.target).hasClass() Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run certain processes on mousedown anywhere in the document, but different ones depending on whether or not certain elements are clicked.  The below code isn't working.  Thanks for any help!

```
$(document).on('mousedown',function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('.item')) {
        console.log('item');
    } else {
        console.log('not item);
    }
});
```

Comment: `.item` is a selector for the `item` class name. Try `!$(e.target).hasClass('item')`.

Comment: What the hell am I thinking?  Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

to hasClass() you should pass the class name, not class selector

```
$(document).on('mousedown',function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('item')) {
        console.log('item');
    } else {
        console.log('not item');
    }
});
```

Comment: I feel like a moron.  Thanks.  >.<